# Question about a particular proof of a proposition from multivariable calculus, concerning the gradient.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Notation: $(x,y,z) \equiv (x^{1},x^{2},x^{3})$.

Consider a cartesian coordinate system and the euclidian vector space $\mathbb{E}^{3} \equiv (\mathbb{R}^{3},\ \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$. Consider,also,the following proposition:

> Let be $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ a convex set and $\phi(x,y,z)$ a scalar field. If $$\vec{\nabla} \phi(x,y,z) = \vec{0}_{\mathbb{R}^{3}} = (0,0,0)$$
>   then $\phi(x,y,z) = constant$ in $\Omega$

My guess:

The gradient vector is then: $$\vec{\nabla} \phi(x,y,z) = \sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^{i}}\vec{e}_{i}$$

Where $\vec{e}_{i}$ are the canonical basis of $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ in cartesian coordinates, i.e. $$\beta = [\vec{e}_{1},\vec{e}_{2},\vec{e}_{3}] \equiv [\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}]$$

Then,

$$\vec{\nabla} \phi(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\vec{j} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\vec{k}$$

But,

$$\vec{\nabla} \phi(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\vec{j} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\vec{k} = (0,0,0) $$

Then,

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=0 \\ 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=0 \\ 
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=0 \implies \phi = \int dx + g(y,z) = 1 + g(y,z) = k^{1}$$

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=0 \implies \phi = \int dy + h(x,z) = 1+ h(x,z) = k^{2}$$

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}=0 \implies \phi = \int dz + j(x,y) = 1 +j(x,y) = k^{3}$$

Then, $\phi$ is a constant field in $\Omega$.

Is my "proof" right?

Comment: Terrible.  As gradient dot product gradient = 0, the square of partial derivatives, hence the partial derivatives are 0.  How you show the scalar is constant is confusion.

Comment: Could you please write a simple proof or hint?

Comment: The set $\Omega$ must be open also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z) = \phi(x,y,z).$
$\nabla f • \nabla f = f_x^2 + f_y^2 + f_z^2 = 0.$
$f_x = f_y = f_z = 0$

Thus exists a,b,c with
$f(x,y,z) = f(a,y,z) = f(a,b,z) = f(a,b,c).$

The 1st equation because f is constant on x.
Likewise for the other equations.